# Indicate that a function is used externally in Webstorm

Tags: javascript, typescript, webstorm

I feel I'm overlooking something here.  I've created a nice Typescript file, but WebStorm complains that all my functions are 'Unused'.  Well, they are .. just not locally to the file itself.  Is there some JSDoc or other commented code I can put in to tell WebStorm that I KNOW this function IS used .. just used externally?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes - `//noinspection JSUnusedGlobalSymbols`; hit `Alt+Enter` on your function that is reported to be unused, then hit `Right` and choose '`Suppress for statement`'